# Are Two People Considered a Single Person When Married

Tags: united-states, marriage

In the United States of America is a married couple, regardless of sex, considered to be a single person by the government? If so, in what situations does the government not view them as a single person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modern rule is that individuals in a married couple are almost never considered a single person (ownership of real property in a tenancy by entireties in a few states mostly in the Northeast, is a narrow and rare exception).

Historically, considering a married man and woman to be a single person (a legal doctrine called *coverture*) was common place in the common law, but almost all such rules have been superseded.

Lots of the relevant law and legal history is considered in the [answer to this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/have-wives-ever-been-legally-a-mans-property-in-the-us/22642#22642) at Law.SE.