# What sorts of “necessities” could married women enter contracts for?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, marriage, legal-history

A [recent answer by @Ohwilleke](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/22642/48046) on the historical status of married women lists the limited types of contracts they could enter into.

One of these of those for necessities. What is referred to by this?

Comment: Please could you link to the referenced answer?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff no problem. https://law.stackexchange.com/a/22642/48046

Answer (score 1):

### The same sorts of necessities children can enter contracts for

Necessities means pretty much what you’d think it means - the things that are necessary to maintain your life and lifestyle. So, food, clothing, shelter, utilities, entertainment, transport, education etc. all appropriate to the person’s economic circumstances - bus fare for a poor person, chauffeur drive limousines for the super wealthy.